# Magento 2 Admin Broken

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I've got a Magento 2 dev installation all setup, I've pulled from my repo and setup the site.

The frontend seems to be working OK, I can see information being pulled from the database.

The issue is when I try and do anything in the admin, it's just broken, the Magento logo isn't showing on the top left and none of the sub-menus is working.

I have this error in the console:

`http://domain.co.uk/static/version1570049246/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I've tried setting the site to developer mode, clearing cache, upgrading and compiling again but with no such luck.

Any help would be great.

**EDIT**

After looking in this folder:

`pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs`

I can't see the require.js file, does this need to be symlinked?

Comment: Try this `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml`

Comment: also please check if your `pub/static` has `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks @RizwanKhan there is a .htaccess there.

Comment: Thanks @PЯINCƏ I've tried that but unfortunately, it's not worked.